# Spark.ml regressions do not calculate same models as scikit-learn

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I am setting up a very simple logistic regression problem in scikit-learn and in spark.ml, and the results diverge: the models they learn are different, but I can't figure out why (data is the same, model type is the same, regularization is the same...).

No doubt I am missing some setting on one side or the other. Which setting? How should I set up either scikit or spark.ml to find the same model as its counterpart?

I give the sklearn code and spark.ml code below. Both should be ready to cut-and-paste and run.

### scikit-learn code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, Ridge

X = np.array([
    [-0.7306653538519616, 0.0],
    [0.6750417712898752, -0.4232874171873786],
    [0.1863463229359709, -0.8163423997075965],
    [-0.6719842051493347, 0.0],
    [0.9699938346531928, 0.0],
    [0.22759406190283604, 0.0],
    [0.9688721028330911, 0.0],
    [0.5993795346650845, 0.0],
    [0.9219423508390701, -0.8972778242305388],
    [0.7006904841584055, -0.5607635619919824]
])

y = np.array([
    0.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
])

m, n = X.shape

# Add intercept term to simulate inputs to GameEstimator
X_with_intercept = np.hstack((X, np.ones(m)[:,np.newaxis]))

l = 0.3
e = LogisticRegression(
    fit_intercept=False,
    penalty='l2',
    C=1/l,
    max_iter=100,
    tol=1e-11)

e.fit(X_with_intercept, y)

print e.coef_
# => [[ 0.98662189  0.45571052 -0.23467255]]

# Linear regression is called Ridge in sklearn
e = Ridge(
    fit_intercept=False,
    alpha=l,
    max_iter=100,
    tol=1e-11)

e.fit(X_with_intercept, y)

print e.coef_
# =>[ 0.32155545  0.17904355  0.41222418]
```

### spark.ml code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object TestSparkRegression {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sparkTrainingData = new SQLContext(sc)
      .createDataFrame(Seq(
        LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(-0.7306653538519616, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.6750417712898752, -0.4232874171873786)),
        LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.1863463229359709, -0.8163423997075965)),
        LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(-0.6719842051493347, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.9699938346531928, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.22759406190283604, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.9688721028330911, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(0.5993795346650845, 0.0)),
        LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(0.9219423508390701, -0.8972778242305388)),
        LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(0.7006904841584055, -0.5607635619919824))))
      .toDF("label", "features")

    val logisticModel = new LogisticRegression()
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .fit(sparkTrainingData)

    println(s"Spark logistic model coefficients: ${logisticModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${logisticModel.intercept}")
    // Spark logistic model coefficients: [0.5451588538376263,0.26740606573584713] Intercept: -0.13897955358689987

    val linearModel = new LinearRegression()
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setSolver("l-bfgs")
      .fit(sparkTrainingData)

    println(s"Spark linear model coefficients: ${linearModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${linearModel.intercept}")
    // Spark linear model coefficients: [0.19852664861346023,0.11501200541407802] Intercept: 0.45464906876832323

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: There is some sort of randomness when an estimator is initialized, or data is split into train and test. Have you considered the `random_state` in scikit? I am sure there must be something like that in Spark.

Comment: I don't quite buy it. Given enough iterations, both should converge to the same model. This problem is convex, so there is a single minimum. Randomness could play a role in the presence of multiple optima, but no here, IMHO.

Comment: That may be the case.Please show the results of spark comparable to scikit. Also There is a [LinearRigression()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) available in scikit.

Comment: The results are shown with the code for both. For scikit, I used Ridge, should be the same as spark.ml LinearRegression with regularization parameter. Scikit LinearRegression, if I understand correctly, is OLS without regularization (I could be wrong, I'm new to scikit).

Answer (score 16):

You need to do the following:

1. Standardize both the python and spark dataframes first. Spark uses standardization by default internally. Take care to account for differences in standard deviation formulas in standardscaler implementations in both the packages.
2. For logistic regression, Spark uses average of log-loss (denominator being sum of weights, which is number of training instances when all weights are 1) whereas sklearn uses sum of log-loss. In linear regression, spark uses a 1/2n factor in the sum of squared errors term unlike sklearn. Spark regularization needs to be scaled down accordingly - 1/10 times for logistic regression, and 1/20 times for linear regression in this example.

**Scikit-learn code**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, Ridge

X = np.array([
    [-0.7306653538519616, 0.0],
    [0.6750417712898752, -0.4232874171873786],
    [0.1863463229359709, -0.8163423997075965],
    [-0.6719842051493347, 0.0],
    [0.9699938346531928, 0.0],
    [0.22759406190283604, 0.0],
    [0.9688721028330911, 0.0],
    [0.5993795346650845, 0.0],
    [0.9219423508390701, -0.8972778242305388],
    [0.7006904841584055, -0.5607635619919824]
])

y = np.array([
    0.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
])

m, n = X.shape


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

## sqrt(n-1)/sqrt(n) factor for getting the same standardization as spark
Xsc=StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)*3.0/np.sqrt(10.0)

l = 0.3
e = LogisticRegression(
    fit_intercept=True,
    penalty='l2',
    C=1/l,
    max_iter=100,
    tol=1e-11,
    solver='lbfgs',verbose=1)

e.fit(Xsc, y)

print e.coef_, e.intercept_
# => [[ 0.82122437 0.32615256]] [-0.01181534]

#e.get_params(deep=True)

# Linear regression is called Ridge in sklearn
e = Ridge(
    fit_intercept=True,
    alpha=l,
    max_iter=100,
    tol=1e-11)

e.fit(Xsc, y)

print e.coef_,e.intercept_
# =>[ 0.21310109 0.09203616] 0.5
```

**Spark Code (refactored to use ML API)**

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler

val sparkTrainingData_orig = new SQLContext(sc).
  createDataFrame(Seq(
    (0.0, Vectors.dense(Array(-0.7306653538519616, 0.0))),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.6750417712898752, -0.4232874171873786))),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.1863463229359709, -0.8163423997075965))),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense(Array(-0.6719842051493347, 0.0))),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.9699938346531928, 0.0))),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.22759406190283604, 0.0))),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.9688721028330911, 0.0))),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.5993795346650845, 0.0))),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.9219423508390701, -0.8972778242305388))),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense(Array(0.7006904841584055, -0.5607635619919824))))).
  toDF("label", "features_orig")

val sparkTrainingData=new StandardScaler().
  setWithMean(true).
  setInputCol("features_orig").
  setOutputCol("features").
  fit(sparkTrainingData_orig).
  transform(sparkTrainingData_orig)

//Make regularization 0.3/10=0.03
val logisticModel = new LogisticRegression().
  setRegParam(0.03).
  setLabelCol("label").
  setFeaturesCol("features").
  setTol(1e-12).
  setMaxIter(100).
  fit(sparkTrainingData)

println(s"Spark logistic model coefficients: ${logisticModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${logisticModel.intercept}")
// Spark logistic model coefficients: [0.8212244419577079,0.32615245441495727] Intercept: -0.011815325216668142

//Make regularization 0.3/20=0.015    
val linearModel = new LinearRegression().
  setRegParam(0.015).
  setLabelCol("label").
  setFeaturesCol("features").
  setTol(1e-12).
  setMaxIter(100).
  fit(sparkTrainingData)

println(s"Spark linear model coefficients: ${linearModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${linearModel.intercept}")
// Spark linear model coefficients: [0.21394341729353747,0.09257340293212045] Intercept: 0.5
```

Comment: v nice analysis