# Using R to verify the coefficients computed from spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel

Tags: r, apache-spark, linear-regression

any idea how to use R to verify the coefficients computed from spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel?  I've tried the lm() function in R, but the two sets of coefficients from R and Spark are quite different. Maybe I should use other function in R?

```
// transform dataframe
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = dataRDD.map{case(fdate, adHashValue, effectDummyArray, timeDummyArray, label) =>
val features = Vectors.dense(effectDummyArray ++ timeDummyArray)
  (label, features)
}.toDF("label", "features")

// set up model
val lr = new LinearRegression().setRegParam(0.3)


val lr_model = lr.fit(df)
val summary = lr_model.summary
val PValues = summary.pValues
val Variance = summary.coefficientStandardErrors.map{x => x * x}
val coefficients: Array[Double] = lr_model.coefficients.asInstanceOf[DenseVector].values
```

Comment: can you reproduce `lm` if you use no regularisation `setRegParam(0.)` ?

Comment: In that case I would not get p-value for the coefficients in spark. I've tried to setRegParam(0.), it generated the error: no p-value available for this linearregressionmodel.

Comment: okay too bad; It was just a suggestion from glancing at the [online docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.html). bit weird though as I'd of thought adding the regularisation would stop the standard errors being produced rather than the other way around.

Comment: there may also be some scaling going on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729431/spark-ml-regressions-do-not-calculate-same-models-as-scikit-learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  Set the regParam close to 0. could do just fine.
`setRegParam(0.00001).setSolver("normal")`